# Perl Mail::IMAPClient with IO::Socket::SSL help

Tags: perl, imap

I am in the process of working on a perl script that will connect to Gmail and download all the emails. Do keep in mind that I'm only concentrating on connecting to Gmail at the moment, so the script is only set up to cycle through some folders for now. This is what I have so far:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Mail::IMAPClient;
use IO::Socket::SSL;

# Connect to IMAP via SSL and get rid of greeting message

my $socket = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
 PeerAddr  =>  'imap.gmail.com',
 PeerPort  => 993,
 )
 or die "Socket(): $@";

my $greeting = <$socket>;
my ($id, $answer) = split /\s+/, $greeting;
die "Problems loggin in: $greeting" if $answer ne 'OK';

# Build a client attached to the SSL Socket and login

my $client = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
 Socket => $socket,
 User => 'mail@gmail.com',
 Password => 'password',
 Port  => 993,
 )
 or die "new(): $@";

my ($code, $output) = ("","");
until( $code ) {
 $output = $client->_read_line or return undef;
 for my $o (@$output) {
  $client->_debug("Connect: Recieved this from readline: ".join("/",@$o)."\n");
  $client->_reord($client->Count,$o);
  next unless $o->[Mail::IMAPClient::TYPE] eq "OUTPU";
  ($code) = $o->[Mail::IMAPClient::DATA] =~ /^\*\s+(OK|BAD|NO)/i ;
 }
}

if($code =~ /BYE|NO /) {
 $client->State("Unconnected");
 die "IMAP server disconnected";
}

$client->login;

print "1";

$client->select('INBOX');
my @mails = ($client->seen(),$client->unseen);
foreach my $id (@mails) { print "$id\n"; }
# Terminate the connection with IMAP

$client->logout();
```

When I run the script, however, the program only sits with a blinking cursor for a long period of time. It returns absolutely no output or errors. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: On which line is it stuck? (the debugger can help you, or the poor man's method of sprinkling print statements throughout your code.)

Comment: Well, dispersing print commands doesn't return any output. Even putting one at the head of the perl file doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I still don't have it working, but I changed the code above. With this new code I get the following output: Trying command when NOT connected! LastError was: timeout waiting 600s for data from server at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/IMAPClient.pm line 116
 Mail::IMAPClient::LastError('Mail::IMAPClient=HASH(0xd57708)', 'NO not connected') called at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/IMAPClient.pm line 1617
 Mail::IMAPClient::_read_line('Mail::IMAPClient=HASH(0xd57708)') called at spam.pl line 32
Can't return outside a subroutine at spam.pl line 32.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It might be easier to use a module that does the IMAP with SSL for you.
I have used both [Net::IMAP::Simple::SSL](http://search.cpan.org/~cwest/Net-IMAP-Simple-SSL-1.3/lib/Net/IMAP/Simple/SSL.pm) and [Mail::Cclient](http://search.cpan.org/~micb/Mail-Cclient-1.1/Cclient.pm) to connect to IMAP servers over SSL, although I haven't tried to connect to Gmail.

Also, I haven't used [Mail::IMAPClient](http://search.cpan.org/~plobbes/Mail-IMAPClient-3.25/lib/Mail/IMAPClient.pod), which you are using, but it does appear to support SSL, and mentions Gmail several times in the documentation, so it should work without having to create your own SSL sockets.